# Ember JS, Patch Record REST Adapter

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js

Is there a way with Ember JS to use the `PATCH` verb in order to partially update a record on the server (instead of `PUT` which will override the whole record).

**Creating a record**

Using `POST` which is all good.

```
var car = store.createRecord('car', {
  make: 'Honda',
  model: 'Civic'
});
car.save(); // => POST to '/cars'
```

**Modifying a record**

Always using `PUT` which is not ideal.

```
car.set('model', 'Accord')
car.save(); // => PUT to '/cars/{id}'
```

I would like to have the control over the HTTP verb used for saving.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a way to do it, but you'll have to do a bit of work. Specifically, you'll need to override the [updateRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_updateRecord) method in the adapter. Modifying the [default implementation](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/e89732a5aefb6a81b46927da1c6f048f4aede85e/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest-adapter.js#L621), you should come up with something like this:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    updateRecord(store, type, snapshot) {
        const payload = {};
        const changedAttributes = snapshot.changedAttributes();

        Object.keys(changedAttributes).forEach((attributeName) => {
            const newValue = changedAttributes[attributeName][1];
            // Do something with the new value and the payload
            // This will depend on what your server expects for a PATCH request
        });

        const id = snapshot.id;
        const url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, id, snapshot, 'updateRecord');

        return this.ajax(url, 'PATCH', payload);
    }
});
```

You'll have to dig into the [Snapshot](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Snapshot.html) documentation a bit to generate the request payload, but it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: hey @GJK, may I know how to call the save method on the model, is this simple model.save()?

Answer (score -2):

you can use `save()` in ember which uses the PATCH verb.
Records that already exist on the backend are updated using the HTTP PATCH verb.

```
store.findRecord('post', 1).then(function(post) {
  post.get('title'); // => "Rails is Omakase"

  post.set('title', 'A new post');

  post.save(); // => PATCH to '/posts/1'
});
```

look for more details [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/)

Comment: Please demonstrate how that works in the answer itself.

Comment: *"Records that already exist on the backend are updated using the HTTP PATCH verb."* from: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/

Comment: The documentation referenced in this answer conflicts with the documentation for specific EmberData adapters.  The updateRecord method, which is invoked when saving existing records, uses the PUT verb, which will replace an entire record rather than only update supplied fields as expected with PATCH.  https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.24/classes/RESTAdapter/methods/updateRecord?anchor=updateRecord